# I have a error when audio .wav file import in vue.js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, audio

When I have imported audio file and save vue file. after compiling showing me this error

> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:4)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> (Source code omitted for this binary file)

here is my imported code

```
var audio = new Audio(require('@/assets/files/wrong-answer-sound.wav')) // path to file
    audio.play()
```

here is my file folder path
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffGSs.png)

Comment: I am 95% confident this is incorrect usage of `require` https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/

Answer (score 0):

Try make an html tag on your page

```
<audio src="@/assets/files/wrong-answer-sound.wav"></audio>
```

And then activate it in your code. Take this tag with `ref` or `document.querySelector`
If you need a dynamic audio, you can do this with computed source and pass to `src` attribute in your audio tag a variable or computed property

Comment: basically, I want when I click button then call a method and play this audio. That's why I use like this way without using html audio tag

Comment: If so, you can make audio.play() in a method, style audio tag so it would be invisible and call method for starting audio on click

Answer (score 0):

This is Laravel vue.js project. So the audio file is not a run-time file that's why I have to keep the audio file in Laravel public folder. Then I have to use it like this way.I use below code in vue file

```
var audio = new Audio('/correct.mp3') // path to file
audio.play()
```

That's working perfectly